# Simple text formatting in Latex

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'd like to do the following in `LaTeX` (it's being fed to pandoc for conversion)
I use the `mainfont` and `mainfontoptions` in pandoc. I have a piece of text on top that I'd like centered, and set to the fonts specified in the command line. The rest of the text I'd like to just be the default.

If I put in something like:

```
\centering Text
```

It centers fine, but also centers the rest of the document. It also doesn't use the font I want to use.

If I do

```
# Text
```

It uses the font (and makes it bold) but doesn't center. Ideally, I'd like to figure out some way to do a one-line `\center` and #.

Comment: `#` used this way is definitely not LaTeX. Maybe you wanted to use `{\centering\Huge Text\par}`, or `\begin{center}\Huge Text\end{center}`.

Comment: (question bumped by Community) OP briefly mentioned pandoc. Question could have [tag:pandoc] added however

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I can do:

```
\Huge\centerline{Text}\large
```

and get what I want

Comment: I'm afraid this is not very good. 1) `\large` will affect whatever comes after it. 2) `\centerline` is from plain TeX, not LaTeX (sometimes, this can be acceptable, though). 3) The scope of `\Huge` is not limited here (though `\large` will override it). See my suggestions above—I hope they work in your system.

Comment: THe above works, but prevents the line from line-wrapping, whereas using \begin... /end wraps it up. I actually want the rest of the text large, anyway, so no big deal. Thx

Comment: It would be better to use `\centerline{\Huge text}{\large other text}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the SE bot bumped this question up after 3 years, but it does need some explanation:

Many LaTeX commands apply an effect, which continues indefinitely. Among these are `\centering`, `\large`, and similar commands.

In order to confine the effect, it is necessary to use a group. If the extent of the effect is very lengthy (much typing), the best approach is to bound the group using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` because they are easier to find, when you edit the text. But if the effect does not involve much typing,
it is easy to use braces `{ }` to delimit the group.

Example: `{\centering This text is centered.\par}`

Example: `{\large This text is large} but this is not.`

Note that `\centering` requires `\par` within the group. Also, you cannot use another `\par` mid-way, but you can break lines using `\\` if desired.

Some commands can span multiple paragraphs within the group. Other commands must confine their effect to within a single paragraph. There are many possible situations, depending on the command (and possibly depending on which package defines the command. Experiment.